# how to block virtual keyboard while clicking on edittext in android?

Tags: android

How to block `virtual keyboard` while clicking on edittext  in android

Answer (score 46, accepted):

[Here](http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/180530f680374493?pli=1) is a website that will give you what you need.

As a summary, it provides links to `InputMethodManager` and `View` from Android Developers. It will reference to the `getWindowToken` inside of `View` and `hideSoftInputFromWindow()` for `InputMethodManager`.

A better answer is given in the link, hope this helps.

#### EDIT

From the link posted above, here is an example to consume the `onTouch` event:

```
editText.setOnTouchListener(otl);

private OnTouchListener otl = new OnTouchListener() {
    public boolean onTouch (View v, MotionEvent event) {
        return true; // the listener has consumed the event
    }
};
```

Here is another example from the same website. This claims to work but seems like a bad idea since your `EditBox` is `NULL` it will be no longer an editor:

```
myEditor.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener(){
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        int inType = myEditor.getInputType(); // backup the input type
        myEditor.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL); // disable soft input
        myEditor.onTouchEvent(event); // call native handler
        myEditor.setInputType(inType); // restore input type
        return true; // consume touch event
    }
});
```

Hope this points you in the right direction!

Comment: after trying 5+ other suggestions, finally a solution to this that works.

Comment: @JohnyTex I haven't tried the suggested solution, but I would see if the answer below, (e.g., http://stackoverflow.com/a/12950947/166712) solves that problem.

Comment: Tried it, but I don't understand that solution.

Comment: If you are using data binding, add this to your EditText layout: android:onTouch="@{() -> true}"

Comment: @Thilaw Brics if you pasted your layout I would be happy to help. Probably worth creating a separate question.

Comment: <EditText
                android:id="@+id/startingDate"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="@string/starting_date"
                android:onTouch="@{() -> true}"
                android:inputType="date" />

What I get in fact is that the xml editor does not recognize the attribute you provided, even when I use data binding

Answer (score 7):

A simpler way, is to set focusable property of `EditText` to `false`.

In your xml layout:

```
<EditText
    ...
    android:focusable="false" />
```

Comment: Thanks! best solution for me as i only want to show the Time/datepicker when a user clicks on the EditText!

Comment: @Symfony Dev sorry but you can still long press on edittext and edit them. Check Anthony answer as it's a correct solution.

Answer (score 3):

Another simpler way is adding `android:focusableInTouchMode="false"` line to your `EditText`'s xml. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

For cursor positioning you can use `Selection.setSelection(...)`, i just tried this and it worked:

```
final EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edittext);
editText.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
     @Override
     public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {

         //change the text here

         Selection.setSelection(editText.getText(), editText.length());
         return true;
     }
});
```

Comment: I don't understand what you mean with change text here. Would you mind explaining further?

Comment: I have a hard time seeing this putting the cursor at any other position than at the end, but I don't know...?

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is by setting the flag `textIsSelectable` in EditText to **true**. This will hide the SoftKeyboard permanently for the EditText but also will provide the added bonus of retaining the cursor and you'll be able to select/copy/cut/paste.

You can set it in your xml layout like this:

```
<EditText
    android:textIsSelectable="true"
    ...
/>
```

Or programmatically, like this:

```
EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
editText.setTextIsSelectable(true);
```

For anyone using API 10 and below, hack is provided here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/20173020/7550472