# How to hide the soft keyboard on EditText

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard, android-keypad

I want to hide soft keyboard on EditText even on 'click' also. I mean to say there should not be visible soft keyboard in my activity, because I am having own keyboard to enter data. 
Please help me... Thanks...

Comment: You might find [this article](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/on-screen-inputs.html) helpful, from the Android Developers site. Let me know if it doesn't answer your question.

Comment: see this post http://stackoverflow.com/a/1109108/985143

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to close/hide the Android Soft Keyboard?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1109022/how-to-close-hide-the-android-soft-keyboard)

Comment: @Adil Soomro, I am unable to get the solution from that link... still soft keyboard is visible when i click on edittext...

Comment: I am unable to get the solution from that link... still soft keyboard is visible when i click on edittext...

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to hide soft keyboard on android after clicking outside EditText?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4165414/how-to-hide-soft-keyboard-on-android-after-clicking-outside-edittext)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 editText_input_field.setOnTouchListener(otl);

 private OnTouchListener otl = new OnTouchListener() {
 public boolean onTouch (View v, MotionEvent event) {
        return true; // the listener has consumed the event
}
};
```

source  : [how to block virtual keyboard while clicking on edittext in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1845285/how-to-block-virtual-keyboard-while-clicking-on-edittext-in-android)

Comment: this is nice, and here we have to get focus on the specified view thats why we have to get the request on that. so Its better to add `((EditText)v).requestFocus()` above `return true;'

Comment: without @Noundla 's comment the editbox won't be focusable on touch

Answer (score 1):

Set EditText widget's inputType to `null` like this,

```
editTExt.setInputType(TYPE_NULL);
```

Comment: @noundla.. its a constant in **InputType** class.. try **InputYpe.TYPE_NULL**

Comment: ok.. it is worked fine for the only the edittext which has focus already.. If i move to another edittext then the softkeyboard is coming...

Comment: yup.... I have already set that for all views.. anyway i got solution using the below answer which i tick accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

paste below code in your xml file under edittext tag

```
android:textIsSelectable="true"
```