# hiding soft keypad issue

Tags: android, soft-keyboard

I have a gridview which contains edittexts on the activity and below that there is a custom keypad as you can see in below code I added buttons to enter digits. But the problem is soft keypad is popping up whenever I click on edittexts in the gridview.

I tried putting `android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"` in manifest file, but it doesn't even hide the soft keypad in my case. I referred lot of sources including stackoverflow without even leaving a single post. I think there is a problem in my main.xml file. Can't we hide this in childs of gridview(I know this seems silly, but this is the final doubt I am getting after trying a lot of things). Can someone please suggest where I am going wrong? It would be greatly appreciated if you test the following code with your answer and then suggest me if it works.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

        <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/fLayout1"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:background="@drawable/background3">
        <GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
                android:id="@+id/gridview"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:columnWidth="18dp"
                android:numColumns="6"
                android:verticalSpacing="0dp"
                android:horizontalSpacing="1dp"
                android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:listSelector="@null"/>
        </FrameLayout>

        <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/fLayout2"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="4"
                android:background="@drawable/background2">

        <TableLayout
                xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:id="@+id/keypad"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:stretchColumns="*">

        <TableRow>
        <Button android:id="@+id/keypad_1"
        android:text="1"
        android:background="@drawable/custombutton">
        </Button>
        <Button android:id="@+id/keypad_2"
        android:text="2"
        android:background="@drawable/custombutton">
        </Button>
        <Button android:id="@+id/keypad_3"
        android:text="3"
        android:background="@drawable/custombutton">
        </Button>

        <Button android:id="@+id/keypad_4"   
        android:text="4"
        android:background="@drawable/custombutton">
        </Button>

        <Button android:id="@+id/keypad_5"
        android:text="5"
        android:background="@drawable/custombutton">
        </Button>

        </TableRow>
        <TableRow>



        <Button android:id="@+id/keypad_6"
        android:text="6"
        android:background="@drawable/custombutton">
        </Button>

        <Button android:id="@+id/keypad_7"
        android:text="7"
        android:background="@drawable/custombutton">
        </Button>
        <Button android:id="@+id/keypad_8"
        android:text="8"
        android:background="@drawable/custombutton">
        </Button>
        <Button android:id="@+id/keypad_9"
        android:text="9"
        android:background="@drawable/custombutton"> 
        </Button>

        <Button android:id="@+id/keypad_10"
        android:text="C"
        android:background="@drawable/custombutton">
        </Button>

        </TableRow>
        <TableRow>
        <Button android:id="@+id/submit"
        android:text="submit"
        android:layout_span="5"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/custombutton">

        </Button>
        </TableRow>
        </TableLayout>

        </FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: @Shrikant You can check my questions, how can I accept an answer if the given solution is not even giving hints for my problem. I dont

Comment: If you are not getting proper answers to your question, then check if you have explained question nicely. I am sure you might have read but still I would suggest you to always read FAQs before posting a question on this website.

Comment: It seems like an argument to me. I would be pleased if you can ask me now, in case you have any doubts in my questions. This question is no exception. Of course I always express gratitude because at least they are trying to help solve my problem.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried adding this line in the `onCreate()` method?

`getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_HIDDEN);`

OR

try what you did before in the manifest but instead of `stateHidden` write `stateAlwaysHidden`

OR

have you tried placing an `onTouch` listener on the `EditText`? If i'm not mistaken it will "consume" the touch event and the keyboard should not appear. 
Something like:

```
editText_input_field.setOnTouchListener(otl);

private OnTouchListener otl = new OnTouchListener() {
    public boolean onTouch (View v, MotionEvent event) {
            return true; // the listener has consumed the event
    }
 };
```

taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1845285/how-to-block-virtual-keyboard-while-clicking-on-edittext-in-android)

let me know if anything works :). I'll think of some other solutions if not ...

Comment: Thanks for your response. Even I tried these too previously. Didn't work. Finally editText.setFocusable(false); worked, but it is not highlighting the edittext when clicked and cursor is also not visible. So, I can't use this too. Even I tried requestFocus, but didn't work.

Comment: I tried this too previously: editText.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
             
                public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

                    editText.setFocusable(true);
                    editText.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
                    return false;
                }
            });          but didn't work. Your's too now but didn't work. Now it's completely disabling edittexts.

Comment: Thank you so much for your time. +1 for that. Please let me know if you find any other solution.