# Hiding the soft keyboard when typing in EditText in Android 4

Tags: android, android-edittext, calculator, virtual-keyboard

I am writing a calculator for Android, for inputting expression I use EditText. As I create my buttons - I do not need a software keyboard, but I want to change the cursor position, text selection, copy, paste. In a word - everything as it is, only the virtual keyboard is not displayed.
In version 2.3 I could write:

```
EditText.setInputType (InputType.TYPE_NULL);
```

and it worked perfectly. In version 4 of the cursor is not displayed, the menu does not work, etc. Tried a bunch of ways - you can not move the cursor, the keyboard is displayed, and it was never really explained.

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(
    Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(myEditText.getWindowToken(), 0); //cursor not showing
------------------------------------------------------------------------
getWindow().setSoftInputMode(
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN); //not working
```

I want to make it as in Panecal, MobiCalc Free, Scientific Calculator. I would be happy with any helpful suggestions on this.
P.S. Sorry for my English.

Answer (score 2):

From the link posted below, here is an example to consume on touch for an Edittext

```
editText_input_field.setOnTouchListener(otl);

private OnTouchListener otl = new OnTouchListener() {
    public boolean onTouch (View v, MotionEvent event) {
            return true; // the listener has consumed the event
    }
 };
```

Here is another example from the same website. This claims to work but seems like a bad idea since your EditBox is NULL it will be no longer an editor:

```
MyEditor.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener(){ 
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        int inType = MyEditor.getInputType(); // backup the input type
        MyEditor.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL); // disable soft input
        MyEditor.onTouchEvent(event); // call native handler
        MyEditor.setInputType(inType); // restore input type
        return true; // consume touch even
   }
});
```

Hope this points you in the right direction

The above answer was taken from - [how to block virtual keyboard while clicking on edittext in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1845285/how-to-block-virtual-keyboard-while-clicking-on-edittext-in-android/1845307#1845307)

This might work too
    `getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_HIDDEN);`

Comment: in first case keyboard is hide, cursor is blinking, but I can`t move it; second case is the same but cursor set at start of expression; third case absolutely nothing on effect. Thank you for trying to help.

Comment: If you Google how to stop the soft keyboard from comming up you will get more results

Answer (score 0):

The exact solution to this is by setting the flag `textIsSelectable` in EditText to **true**. This will retain the cursor and you'll be able to utilise the basic select/copy/cut/paste,etc functions.You can set it in your xml layout like this:

You can set it programmatically like this:

```
EditText edit_text = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
edit_text.setTextIsSelectable(true);
```

Or in your XML Layout :

```
<EditText
    ...
    android:textIsSelectable="true"
/>
```

For anyone using API 10 and below, hack is provided here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/20173020/7550472