# Keyboard appear automatically on Nexus7 version 4.2

Tags: android, dialog, timepicker

I have a dialog containing a time picker.
On all my other phones, all is OK I click on the button , the dialog (containing time picker) appear. Than I set the time.

On the Nexus 7 version android 4.2. In the landscape mode, when I click on the button the dialog appear and the keyboard appears automatically. I didn't clicked on `TimePicker` yet.

Any one know why I am getting this issue on Nexus7.

Edit: The code is given below

```
private DatePicker mDatePicker;

@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   mDatePicker = (DatePicker) view.findViewById(R.id.date_picker);
   mDatePicker.init(mDate.get(Calendar.YEAR), mDate.get(Calendar.MONTH), mDate.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH), this);
   mDatePicker.clearFocus();
}
```

Comment: Take a look at [this][1]. Let's hope it helps.

Cheers


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1845285/how-to-block-virtual-keyboard-while-clicking-on-edittext-in-android/1845307#1845307

Answer (score 4):

Make the `layout` containing the time picker focusable. And request focus to this `layout`. Then the  `DatePicker` won't get focus and the keyboard will not be displayed.

Answer (score 3):

Have you ever tried to hide your keyboard on button click after your dialog appears? Something like this :

`InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);                                                    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(v.getWindowToken(), 0);`

Comment: So what are you doing exactly and when the keyboard is showing. You are going to landscape mode and after that click on the button and your dialog appears and the keyboard shows up too? If that's the situation can you remove focus of your time picker. It can force the keyboard to shows up too.

Comment: i am opening a dialog that contain a datepicker. On nexus7 the year are focused and the keyboard appear. In other devices the day are focused and no keyboard appear

Comment: Ok, just give a try to remove the focuse of datepicket and give a try

Comment: how can i remove the focus?

Comment: are you using datepicker or datepickerdialog?

Comment: what are you updating? And can you post some code so we can see what are you doing actually?

Comment: i just added the code, i an setting the datepicker in onCreateDialog

Comment: did you try using DatePickerDialog or add your datepicker to AlertDialog using addView?

Comment: The code work fine for all my devices. I only get the issue with Nexus7

Comment: this done using DialogFragments:
public class DateTimePickerFragment extends SherlockDialogFragment implements OnDateChangedListener{

Comment: Nexus 7 witn 4.2.1 or 4.2.2?

Comment: that's 4.2, in the device parameter i have only that 4.2

Answer (score 3):

I ran into this same issue with me calling for the `SoftInputMode`(Keyboard) on one `Activity` in my app and it appearing on all the other `Activities`. So, I finally had to add `android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden"` to my `manifest` file on the `activities` I did not want the `SoftInputMode`(Keyboard) to pop up. This got rid of the keyboard popping up. Here is what my `manifest` `Activity` looks like:

```
<activity
        android:name=".GMax3Main"
        android:label="@string/app_name" 
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.medeasy.GMax3.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Answer (score 2):

you can also try to disable it in Manifest:

```
 <activity
  android:name=".activity.SampleActivity"
  android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
 />
```

Answer (score 2):

Inside your layout, add this tag inside a view that is **not** the `DatePicker`:

```
<SomeView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:doSomethingCool="true">
    <requestFocus/>
</SomeView>
```

This should insure that the `DatePicker` won't get focus and, thus, won't display the keyboard.

Answer (score 2):

Add  the following line to your `activity` in `manifest.xml`

```
     android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden"
```