# Android : How to prevent softkeyboard hidden when hardwarekeyboard input

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard, android-input-method, android-hardware-keyboard, inputmethodmanager

I created `EditText` and applied it to the `showSoftInput` of `InputMethodManager`.
When I enter a physical key, the keyboard is automatically hidden.

I want to prevent the keyboard from automatically being hidden.

I've tried the method below.
1. use showSoftInput Flag `ImputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT`, `SHOW_FORCED`
2. use `InputConnectionWrapper` in EditText, The string and the number work normally. but ctrl, Tab, Alt, F1,F2. Entering a key hides the keyboard.

I expect the keyboard to not be hidden when I enter the physical key.
Thank you for reading.

Comment: see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1845285/how-to-block-virtual-keyboard-while-clicking-on-edittext-in-android/1845307#1845307

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**a good option is just to close the softkeyboard when there is an input from hardware keyboard**

Android classes usually provide event handlers, you can implement when subclassing them. The `Activity` class has the following event handlers:

- `onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)`
- `onKeyLongPress(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)`
- `onKeyMultiple(int keyCode, int repeatCount, KeyEvent event)`
- `onKeyShortcut(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)`
- `onKeyUp(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)`

In addition all views have the following event handlers:

- `onKeyDown(int, KeyEvent)`
- `onKeyUp(int, KeyEvent)`

I guess there are many other classes that have similar event handlers for key events, but this should be enough for your situation. The [KeyEvent](https://developer.android.com/training/keyboard-input/commands) then contains information about the pressed key, i.e. the key code.

**in you case you might want to do something like this :**

in you `activity` or `view` class override on of `onKeyDown` or `onKeyUp` methods and 
hide the softkeyboard in there like:

```
override fun onKeyUp(keyCode: Int, event: KeyEvent?): Boolean {
        hideSoftKeyboard()
        return super.onKeyUp(keyCode, event)
}
```

or you can add a `keyListener` for your edittext

```
mEditText.setOnKeyListener { v, keyCode, event ->
       hideSoftKeyboard()
       return@setOnKeyListener when (keyCode) {
           KeyEvent.ACTION_UP -> {
               hideSoftKeyboard()
               true
           }
           else -> false
       }
}
```

how to close softKeyword:

```
fun hideSoftKeyboard() {
   try {
        val inputMethodManager = getSystemService(
            Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE
        ) as InputMethodManager
        inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(
            currentFocus!!.windowToken, 0)
    } catch (e: Exception) {}
}
```

Comment: I've also tried to block key events.
However, to change the language, the language setting must be sent as an event.
In that case, the virtual keyboard is hidden.

Comment: If enter a key on a physical keyboard, I want to prevent the virtual keyboard from automatically being hidden.
Instead, I think only prevent virtual keyboards from being hidden because keys such as changing language can't be run if block events in the middle.